# Android: declaring colors in xml

Tags: java, android, layout

EDIT I did the suggested changes but I still get the same error, as shown below.

I have a layout to which I'm trying to set the background color dynamically in response to clicks and so on.

This is the XML for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_pare"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_style"
   >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the file where I am trying to declare the colors, stored in Drawable/custom_style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item  android:color="#ff0000" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="#ffffff" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="#e3e3e3"/>
</selector>
```

The problem is that when I try to run this the app crashes with the following error:

```
03-24 16:29:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 16:29:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17643): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML                 file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-24 16:29:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17643):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-24 16:29:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17643):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)...
```

Comment: See my answer there are errors when you declare your colors.

Comment: In your XML you have set the layout_height="fill_pare" if you put fill_parent (or better match_parent) you still have the error? If the error persists can you post the code of the onCreate method of the crashing activity?

Comment: @jaumebd I think you just find the solution! ^^

Comment: I just mispelled it when I copied here. Now I coppied this code to a clean project and I get a "failed to parse drawable/custom_style.xml" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a `color` but a **drawable** (.xml), it should be:

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_style"
```

You should put your `custom_style.xml` in a `drawable` folder:
(Right click on `res` folder and create a folder named `drawable`)

[image]

Also change your `selector` like the following:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item  android:drawable="@color/color_one" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_two" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/color_three"/>
</selector>
```

Into /res/values create a file named `colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="color_one" >#ff0000</color>
    <color name="color_two" >#ffffff</color>
    <color name="color_three" >#e3e3e3</color>
</resources>
```

Finally, referencing your color in your item's selector by `@color/color_name`.

From the reference:

> Note: A color resource can also be used as a drawable in XML. For example, when creating a state list drawable, you can reference a color resource for the android:drawable attribute (android:drawable="@color/green").

---

As @jaumebd (*eagle eye* ^^) said, your problem is this line `android:layout_height="fill_pare"`, this is `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`.

This should work.

Comment: The second xml snipped fives me a "Color types not allowed" error.

Comment: Great, finally id doesn't crash. Still doesn't do what I want it to do though.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:background="@color/custom_style"
```

to

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_style"`
```

And place custom_style.xml in the folder "drawable"

Comment: custom_style is in the folder drawable (not values) ?

Comment: Yes. It gives me the same error. Which is why I had moved it to Colors (sorry, not Values) in the first place.

Comment: insert in your RelativeLayout this line : `android:background=@drawable/custom_style`

Answer (score 0):

You should place the custom_style.xml into your drawable folder.

Change following code in your xml file :

```
android:background="@color/custom_style"
```

to

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_style"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all put your custom_style in res/drawable folder (if it not exists in your project, create it).

In your code you are trying to use a drawable xml as a color, this is the error.

To set the drawable to the background correctly you have to use:

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_style"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `custom_style.xml` should be in the **drawable folder**. Hence your layout XML file would change to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_pare"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_style"
   >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```